# MongoDB - Class Map not applying

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a class called `Entity`, it has an `Id` property which is of type `Guid`. Now by default MongoDb serializes this as binary which is not what I want.

I cannot for the life of me get the Id property to serialize as a `string`.

I have tried both a `ConventionPack` and a `ClassMap`.

Entity Definition:

```
public class Entity : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return this.ContainsKey(nameof(Id)) ? Guid.Parse(this[nameof(Id)].ToString()) : Guid.Empty; }
        set { this[nameof(Id)] = value; }
    }

    public string EntityName
    {
        get { return this.ContainsKey(nameof(EntityName)) ? this[nameof(EntityName)].ToString() : ""; }
        set { this[nameof(EntityName)] = value; }
    }

}
```

Class Map Definition:

```
public class EntityClassMap: BsonClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityClassMap()
    {
        AutoMap();

        GetMemberMap(x => x.Id).SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));

    }
}
```

Class Map registration:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap(new EntityClassMap());
```

Convention

```
public class GuidAsStringRepresentationConvention : ConventionBase, IMemberMapConvention
{
    public void Apply (BsonMemberMap memberMap)
    {
        if (memberMap.MemberType == typeof(Guid))
        {
            memberMap.SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));
        }

    }
}
```

Convention Pack definition and registration:

```
var pack = new ConventionPack() {new GuidAsStringRepresentationConvention()};
ConventionRegistry.Register("GuidAsString", pack, it => true);
```

At a complete loss as to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so apparently none of the class map or convention code was wrong the issue was that the `Entity` object inherited from `Dictionary<string, object>`

When I stopped inheriting from `Dictionary<string, object>` it all started working.

What I was trying to achieve was essentially allow both the statically defined properties and any extra properties to be saved.

It turns out, Mongo will automatically map so called "Extra Elements" to a property that implements `BsonDocument` or `IDictionary<string, object>` if it uses the convention of being called ExtraElements or is configured in a mapping with `MapExtraElementsMember(c => c.Fields);`

It also tidies up my entity class which can now use auto properties:

```
public class Entity 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> Fields { get; set; }  
}
```

Hope this helps someone as it has taken me about a day and a half to figure this out!